# Web App on Azure - Authentication with ADFS

Tags: azure, authentication, web, azure-active-directory, adfs

I have developed a web application written in just pure HTML.

```
<html>
   My code goes here
</html>
```

And I have deployed it to MS Azure. I'm now looking for a way to authenticate this web application with Active Directory so only my organisation's employees can access it.

I have done tons of research online and it seems like there are many ways to do this. However, I'm looking to do it by **"adfs/ls/wia"** (correct me if I'm wrong).

**The reason why I would like to do it only in that way is because:**

I'm going to embed this web application into a dashboard.
In order to view that dashboard, users (employees) need to go to a specific website:

```
https://<dashboard>.<myorganisation>.com
```

And then users will be redirected to a sign-in page with this address:

```
https://fs.<myorganisation>.com/adfs/ls/wia
```

After signing in (with users' active directory accounts), users will be redirected back to the dashboard's website. The URL is now looking like the following:

```
https://<dashboard>.<myorganisation>.com/#/site?:isFromSaml=y
```

And then users can freely browse the dashboards (without having to sign in again) until they close their browsers. So I guess some sort of tokens/sessions are being kept.

**My question is:**

I would like to authenticate my web application with the same way and since it's only accessed after users have signed in, how do I by-pass this authentication step? What do it need to put on top of my HTML code or is there a way to configure this in MS Azure already?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to have two Relying Party in ADFS - one for dashboard - one for web application.

Then you will get SSO across them.

Comment: may I know how I could do so? it seems like the website for dashboards has been integrated with ADFS. How do it do that with the Azure Web Services?
I have tried Azure AD Authentication for my web application but it doesn't go as Single Sign-On. After logging in the dashboard website, users will still need to sign in for that web application. Hope it gives you some extra information.